# Ef core remove child with null

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is my Hierarchical model

```cs
public class MenuModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Url { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Icon { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public MenuModel Parent { get; set; } = null!;
    public ICollection<MenuModel>? Children { get; set; } = new List<MenuModel>();
}
```

Query:

```cs
return await _context.Menus//.Include(o => o.Parent)
                             .Include(m => m.Childrens)
                             .ThenInclude(m => m.Childrens)
                             .Where(m => m.ParentId == null)
                             .ToListAsync();
```

Query is working fine: How to exclude menu without child elements

Please check below..

[image]

I have Added in configuration

```cs
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    })
    .AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
    });
```

But in json file it coming.. Is it possible to exclude in ef core itself? I am using latest EF core preview.

EDIT:
Ef itself count with 0 showing ..How avoid with count=0?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning a default value to the `Children` property, which is why you always see it in your response. To fix this, simply change the `= new List<MenuModel>();` to `= null!;`

```cs
public class MenuModel
{
    ...
    public ICollection<MenuModel>? Children { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ..but i already  removed that also. am using auto mapper map menu to menumodel ..is could be the reason?